# pytest/python fails to import test helper code from within python test

Tags: python, pytest, python-import

I'm having trouble importing test helpers into test code.

The project's python source code and test code directories are separate, but their structure parallels one another.  In the test directory, I have some helper test code that I want to import into the actual tests.  I am setting PYTHONPATH to include both the main src dir and the test dir (details below).

**Command line**:

```
PYTHONPATH="$(pwd)/src/main/python:$(pwd)/src/test/python" poetry run python -m pytest --import-mode=importlib ${@} ./src/test/python
```

**Expectation**:

Importing a test helper module from tests would work.

**Actual**:

```
_ ERROR collecting src/test/python/module_A/module_1/test_file.py _
ImportError while importing test module '/Users/<username>/git/src/test/python/module_A/module_1/test_file.py'.
Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
Traceback:
src/test/python/module_A/module_1/test_file.py: in <module>
    from module_A.module_1.test_helpers.helper_a import HelperA
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module_A.module_1.test_helpers'
```

**Note**:  If I change the test directory structure to no longer parallel the src directory structure, the issue goes away.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.  I'm happy to provide additional information if needed.

**Debug Output**:

I've passed `-v -v -v -v` to python above (`python -v -v -v -v -m pytest . . .`), and I see the following:

```
...
# trying /Users/<username>/git/proj/src/main/python/module_A/test_helpers.cpython-38-darwin.so
# trying /Users/<username>/git/proj/src/main/python/module_A/test_helpers.abi3.so
# trying /Users/<username>/git/proj/src/main/python/module_A/test_helpers.so
# trying /Users/<username>/git/proj/src/main/python/module_A/test_helpers.py
# trying /Users/<username>/git/proj/src/main/python/module_A/test_helpers.pyc
# trying /Users/<username>/git/proj/src/main/python/module_A/test_helpers.cpython-38-darwin.so
# trying /Users/<username>/git/proj/src/main/python/module_A/test_helpers.abi3.so
# trying /Users/<username>/git/proj/src/main/python/module_A/test_helpers.so
# trying /Users/<username>/git/proj/src/main/python/module_A/test_helpers.py
# trying /Users/<username>/git/proj/src/main/python/module_A/test_helpers.pyc
...
```

It appears as thought test_helpers is being looking for in `./src/main/python` twice, but `./src/test/python` isn't searched despite `PYTHONPATH` set to contain the `./src/test/python` path in the command line above.

---

**Example Test Code**:

test_file.py

```
from pytest import mark

# This is where we have an error in the code editor despite
# this running fine.
#
# Import module_A.mocule_1.file could not be resolved
from module_A.test_helpers.helper_a import HelperA

@mark.unit_test
class Handler_tests:
    def test_happy_path(self):
        with HelperA():
            pass
```

helper_a.py (located at `./src/test/python/module_A/test_helpers/`)

```
class HelperA:
    def __init__(self):
        # No impl here
        pass
```

**Project Directory Structure**:

```
// note, some non-python code directories/files exist but are omitted
<proj_root>
├──README.md
├──.env
└──src
    ├── main
    │   └── python
    │       └── module_A
    │           ├── __init__.py
    │           └── module_1
    │               ├── __init__.py
    │               └── file.py
    └── test
        └── python
            ├── conftest.py
            └── module_A
                ├── __init__.py
                └── test_helpers
                    ├── __init__.py
                    └── helper_a
                └── module_1 
                     └── test_file.py
```

**Environment Information**:
Python

```
python ~3.8
pytest 6.0.0
```

VS Code

```
Version: 1.63.0-insider (Universal)
Commit: bedf867b5b02c1c800fbaf4d6ce09cefbafa1592
Date: 2021-11-18T05:17:00.890Z (3 wks ago)
Electron: 13.5.2
Chromium: 91.0.4472.164
Node.js: 14.16.0
V8: 9.1.269.39-electron.0
OS: Darwin arm64 21.1.0
```

Pylance

```
v2021.12.2-pre.1
```

Comment: Try to add `__init__.py` into test/python/module_a/module_1 too, probably it's not that case, but pytest sometimes has problem with that under specific circumstances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, your note gives me some insight what could be going on.

If you use import like that:

```
from module_A.test_helpers.helper_a import HelperA
```

It suggest your PYTHONPATH (so `sys.path`) contains both, `src/main/python` and `src/test/python`.

In order to import module, python looks on all paths in `sys.path` in order and search for specific module. Unfortunately it isn't smart enough to check full path - the first place it finds `module_A` it assumes it's the one and tries to resolve rest path. Your `src/main/python` path is first and for obvious reason it cannot find `test_helpers` there. It doesn't search another paths from `sys.path` and not sure is there a way to force it. The only solution I know is to have different names of files/directories under things you have in PYTHONPATH or use only one pointed to your `src`

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, kosciej16.  I've confirmed this in a way by reversing the order of the paths in PYTHONPATH and see other imports failing that used to succeed.  I am going to do some more reading on this.  It'll take me a few days, but if it all checks out I'll confirm your answer.

Comment: Alright, after reading https://tenthousandmeters.com/blog/python-behind-the-scenes-11-how-the-python-import-system-works/, I'm going with kosciej16's answer.  It looks like there is another option -- use python namespace packages (see section by the same name in the link), but I prefer the rename after reading pytest's discussion of test module loading.